# Germanic loanwords in Czech? The case of "lék"

Tags: germanic-languages, borrowing, slavic-languages

Recently I started studying Czech and I learned the word "lék", pill/medicine and "lékař", doctor/physician. In Polish there is a similar one. They bear a superficial resemblance with Swedish "läke" and, since I have not been able to find a slavic etymology, I was wondering if this could be a germanic loanword.
I was guessing that, if this was a relatively recent loanword, it should have been from German to Czech, but, since I do not recall any similar word in German, maybe this could be a very old loanword from Proto-germanic to Proto-slavic, or something of the like?. My only reference is that other languages (like Finnish) indeed borrowed the word for "medicin" from germanic languages (lääke, in modern Finnish)

Also, I would love to know if there is some sort of digitalized database or something of the like where such things can be checked. I have no formation in linguistics and I don't know many resources.

Comment: It is indeed a Germanic loan. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/lēkijaz) has the loan as being from Gothic rather than Proto-Germanic, though I don’t recall any particular reason off-hand why this should be so. It’s that general area and time frame, though, not modern German.

Comment: Wiktionary as @JanusBahsJacquet said, both English and also in other languages, like [Russian](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/лечить#Этимология).

As far as I know, you're correct that there is no cognate in modern standard German.

Comment: I wouldn't exclude the possibility of Thracian origin.

Comment: This was already discussed at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/36697/why-are-some-russian-and-swedish-words-so-strikingly-similar-%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-tv%C3%A5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4